# Cursor size is different for different line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a content editable div in which 3 lines are seperated by BR tag

Clicking on on Second line leads to bigger Cursor than that in first Line.

```css
.content {
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    first line<br>
    clik here<br>
    lastline
</div>
```

How can we make Cursor size same for all the lines ?

Comment: this is caused by the br height difference. simply remove or set to zero, the line-height property

Comment: @MTroy its not working. can you please update my code

Comment: the render of edit view is more important than the render ?

Comment: Yes. It is .. we need to type something inside that div and hit Enter

Comment: updated code without dom changing. assuming this is a text edit instead of a html edit (who can containing table or something else)

Comment: look for snippet and last code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.content
{
   line-height: 35px; 
}

.content br
{
    display:block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    content: "" !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    first line<br>
    clik here<br>
    lastline
</div>
```

Try to add a specific class to reset br under the content div

The better way, without need to affect the dom
is to prepend a fictive content to each br, to be rendered as a real block

```
.content br
{
    display:block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    content: "" !important;
}
```

Note: defined margins are not really required but usefull to not depending of div line height, and adjusting as you want

Doc:
Look for css [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/content) property
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Looks fine. Thanku so much

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    <div class="content" contenteditable="true"> <span>first line</span> <span>click here</span> <span>lastline</span> </div>

.content{
    line-height: 35px;
}
.content span:nth-child(2){
   padding:10px 0;
}

.content span{
    display:block;
}
```

You can view demo here https://jsfiddle.net/tenigada/wnkehtkg/2/

Comment: Cant change the structure of DOM